# Facing Issue in HtmlAgilityPack package in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, ssis, nuget-package

I added HtmlAgilityPack dll(1.8.5 version) as reference in my SSDT VS 2010 solution.
But i got error message like

> Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.8.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Note : I don't have permission to download dll from Nuget in my original solution so i downloaded dll from another server through Nuget and added that dll in my original solution as reference. Actuall DLL is not in packages folder in my solution.

Please help me on this.

Comment: How did you add the DLL?  Through nuget? We need more information here... Can you confirm the actual DLL is in your packages folder?  You might have to restore nuget packages for the solution

Comment: Actually i don't have permission to download dll from Nuget in my original solution so i downloaded dll from another server through Nuget and added that dll in my original solution as reference. Actuall DLL is not in packages folder in my solution. Thanks

Comment: Those are important details. Add them to your question

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What is the solution for this issue?please suggest

Comment: Did you install the .nupkg to the box with the original solution? Or did you install it on your download box, and just copied the .dll to the original solution box? If you just copied the .dll, I'd try downloading the .nupkg from https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/ (click on the 'Download' link, under the 'Info' heading on the right side of the page). Copy the .nupkg to your development box, and use Package Manager or .NET CLI to install the package.